# SQLITE Cursor does not shows empty values

Tags: android, json, sqlite, cursor

Is there any documentation that says SQLITE Cursor will not show empty values? As you can see the LOGCAT is not showing empty values as well.

If so, how to get empty string ("") for empty fields? I can't populate my JSON with the empty fields. For example, in below case, I want to have 4 elements in each JSON object, but I am getting 2 only.

**CODE:**

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "+KEY_ID+" = 73";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor row = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (row.moveToFirst()) {
    JSONObject prebook;
    do {
        Log.d("a1",""+row.getString(3)); //THIS FIELD IS EMPTY
        Log.d("a2",""+row.getString(2));  //THIS FIELD IS EMPTY
        Log.d("a3",""+row.getString(1)); //THIS FIELD HAS A VALUE
        prebook = new JSONObject();
        prebook.put(KEY_ID, row.getString(0));
        prebook.put(KEY_NAME, row.getString(1));
        prebook.put(KEY_PRINT_NAME, row.getString(2)); // THIS ELEMENT NEVER ADDED INTO THE JSON
        prebook.put(KEY_GENRE, row.getString(3)); // THIS ELEMENT NEVER ADDED INTO THE JSON
    } while (row.moveToNext());
}
```

**LOGCAT:**

```
12-07 12:43:21.480: D/a3(2283): Farmer Boy
```

Comment: There is not such a thing as an empty field. Do you mean null value or empty string (string with a length of `0`)? Also what is the result of that query (regardless of the java code)? Finally what are the datatypes of those fields you're trying to fetch?

Comment: if it is empty, then it is empty. If you want to have something printed out to show the String is empty, do something like this:
String s = row.getString(3);
if("".equals(s)) {
    Log.d("a1",""+"empty"); //THIS FIELD IS EMPTY
} else {
    Log.d("a1",""+s); //THIS FIELD IS EMPTY
}

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho ... Well, they should not be null, because I directly imported from MySql database where all those fields are varchar NOT NULL (in SQLITE, they are TEXT field)... I am sorry I didn't get what do u meant by "what is the result of that query (regardless of the java code)", can you please elaborate?

Comment: Log.d("a1",""+row.getString(3)); //THIS FIELD IS EMPTY
This prints out "a1". Then this "" does not do anything because it is an empty string. and if row.getString(3) is an empty string, meaning it is "" as well, it will not print out anything. In my suggestion I said that if the row.getString(3) is empty, and thus equals "", then let the logcat print out the word "empty" instead.

Comment: @vandus .. sorry I deleted my last comment as I was little late to read the last lines of ur comment .. anyway, shouldn't it just print something like "12-07 12:43:21.480: D/a1(2283): " in my case?

Comment: Just curious, you are using different tags for you Logcat, are you sure you didn't filter the logcat and miss the info?

Comment: oh, I get your idea now...yes it should. Doesn't the LogCat show any other messages instead?

Comment: @vandus and Wenhui ... nope, no filter and nothing else is there in my logcat window ...

Comment: okay, interesting thing, if I change my satetement like "Log.d("a1","test"+row.getString(2));", then it shows "12-07 12:43:21.480: D/a1(2283): test".. that means if logcat text is empty, it just omits whole line! ...

Comment: okay, simple solution .. I have to put something like row.getString(1).toString(), not only row.getString(1).